# Error while generating client from wsdl using apache cxf

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf

I have tried to generate stubs and client from a wsdl using cxf(versions 2.2.3, 2.2.6 and 2.7.0) by giving the below command

```
> wsdl2java.bat -p com.easynet.eordering.client -client  http://expediter.staging.gis.easynet.com:7001/cds/services/eordering?wsdl
```

but I am getting an error as

> WSDLToJava Error: Non unique body parts! In a port, operations must
>   have unique operation signaure on the wire for successful dispatch. In
>   port {http://eordering.uk.easynet.net}eorderingPortSOAP, Operations
>   "{http://eordering.uk.easynet.net}getAMList" and
>   "{http://eordering.uk.easynet.net}getDCList" have the same request
>   body block {http://eordering.uk.easynet.net}userListRequest

I know why this error was thrown, in my wsdl operations are written as

```
<operation name="getDCList"><input message="tns:userListRequest"/><output message="tns:userListResponse"/></operation>
<operation name="getAMList"><input message="tns:userListRequest"/><output message="tns:userListResponse"/></operation>
```

I was just reusing the userListRequest parameter for both the operations, I believe the error was thrown as the same parameter(userListRequest) is specified in both the operations.

Is there any way to avoid this error without making changes to the wsdl ? (as I know operation overloading is not allowed from wsdl 1.2 but input parameters overloading ? ).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Such a WSDL would not be WSI-BasicProfile compliant.  See:

http://www.ws-i.org/profiles/basicprofile-1.1.html#Operation_Signatures

The profile defines the operation signature as the name of the element that would appear in the soap:Body.  Thus, if two operations use the same child element (or message in your case), they are considered non-unique and violating:

```
R2710 The operations in a wsdl:binding in a DESCRIPTION MUST result in operation signatures that are different from one another.
```

Comment: Thanks for the link provided, I thought so but here to avoid the error without changing the wsdl params :-), will change the signatures now.

Answer (score 12):

As mentioned in the question:

> Is there any way to avoid this error without making changes to the wsdl ?

If you can't fix the WSDL, you can disable its validation:

-validate=none

or if you are using Maven:

```
<configuration>
    <wsdlOptions>
        <wsdlOption>
            <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/wsdl/my.wsdl</wsdl>
            <validate>none</validate>
        </wsdlOption>
    </wsdlOptions>
</configuration>
```

Not sure if this is not going to cause problems at runtime. I will find this soon and will update this post.

Comment: If you don't have control over the wsdl then you would not have the option to fix it. My project is already in development for a few months and so far I haven't noticed any drawbacks.

Comment: removed -1 for given explanation

Comment: many a times you have to work with a third party's wsdl. Its not an option to correct the wsdl.

Comment: Comment from users3475860 posted incorrectly in [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39827266/5292302) *After you switched off the validation, what happen then in Runtime? Did you get the classes from a WSDL file or not, because I faced the same problem!! please If you have resolved this problem tell me what can I do?*

Answer (score 0):

If WSDL change is possible and WS-I Basic Profile 2.0 is used, you can add `wsa:Action` with [unique value](http://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-metadata/#actioninwsdl) to element `wsdl:input` (inside element `wsdl:operation`):

E.g.

```
<wsdl:operation name="update">
  <wsdl:input message="tns:myMessage" wsam:Action="namespace/port/operation" />
</wsdl:operation>
```

In WS-I Basic Profile 2.0 the definition of "operation signature":
"The Profile defines the "operation signature" to be the fully qualified name of the child element of SOAP body of the SOAP input message described by an operation in a WSDL binding and the URI value of the wsa:Action SOAP header block, if present."

Answer (score 0):

Another work around is try to get the schema file from the WSDL. and the below plugin in maven to generate the java class

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>schema1-generate</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <extension>true</extension>
                <bindingFiles>
                    <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/service-bindings.xjc</bindingFile>
                </bindingFiles>
                <wsdlDirectory>src/main/resources/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <wsdlFiles>
                    <wsdlFile>Service.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                </wsdlFiles>
                <keep>true</keep>
                <sourceDestDir>target/generated-code/src</sourceDestDir>
                <vmArgs>
                    <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                </vmArgs>
            </configuration>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```